# Issues configuring MongoDB on Dreamhost VPS

Tags: php, apache, mongodb

I have MongoDB up and running - I am able to sign into my VPS via SSH and execute the `mongo` command.

Here is where I run into a problem. Here are some test commands and their output:

```
[*******]$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 1.4.4
url: test
connecting to: test
type "help" for help
> db
test
> db.test.save({a:1});
unauthorized
```

Here is another example of test input and its output:

```
[*******]$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 1.4.4
url: test
connecting to: test
type "help" for help
> use admin
switched to db admin
> db.addUser( { user: "drew", pwd: "myPassword", roles: [ "userAdminAnyDatabase" ] } )
Thu Apr 25 16:34:37 JS Error: uncaught exception: error {
    "$err" : "unauthorized db:admin lock type:-1 client:127.0.0.1",
    "code" : 10057
}
unauthorized db:admin lock type:-1 client:127.0.0.1
```

So I'm a bit stuck - I don't know if this will help or not, but here is some sample code and output when using the PHP class as well:

**Script**

```
<?php
$dbHost = $dbHost = 'mongodb://*******.dreamhostps.com';;
$m = new Mongo($dbHost);
var_dump($m);
?>
```

**Output**

```
object(Mongo)#2 (4) { ["connected"]=> bool(true) ["status"]=> NULL ["server":protected]=> string(33) "mongodb://ps93785.dreamhostps.com" ["persistent":protected]=> NULL }
```

**Other Notes**

Server location was redacted - I am not actually using asterisks.

**Update - output from `fsyncUnlock()`**

```
[*******]$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 1.4.4
url: test
connecting to: test
type "help" for help
> db.fsyncUnlock()
Thu Apr 25 17:36:40 JS Error: TypeError: db.fsyncUnlock is not a function (shell):0
```

Comment: If you have any questions or need any assistance we do have techs available 24/7 and we guarantee a response within 24 hrs of an open ticket. We also have Live Chat as well! Here is a link to [contact support](https://panel.dreamhost.com/index.cgi).

Comment: @DeeJ - The last email I got from you guys said stated that you could not upgrade my MongoDB install - is that the final answer, or can I contact you directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something such as `db.fsyncUnlock()` in Mongo Shell to test if the fsync lock is active and try to repeat the save of any info.

Here is the documentation of the [db.fsyncUnlock](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.fsyncUnlock/#db.fsyncUnlock)

Comment: I added an update to my question with the output from `fsyncUnlock()` - any ideas?

Comment: @anwyatt Yes! Update the MongoDB urgently! (serious, it's very old, the Mongo Shell is actually in version 2.4.3!!! (and your Mongo Shell is in version 1.4.4..))

Comment: Is there an easy way to do that? I used Dreamhost's 1 click install to get the thing added - is there a shell command I can run to update it?

Comment: There are a few options for some distributions of Linux, called "Packages", find it here: http://www.mongodb.org/downloads#packages and, after configuring it correct, call the `(your package manager, apt-get on debian based systems and yum on red hat based systems) upgrade` and, if not work, simply install with via the package. (that can be updated)

Comment: Excellent. This may be over my head, but worst case scenario I can just message a Dreamhost administrator tomorrow. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you can do it too. Good luck! (and says to the Dreamhost administrator to update the MongoDB in the 1 click install, too =P)